# How do we find the pointwise limit of $f_n = x^n + e^{2x}/n^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x) = x^n + \dfrac{e^{2x}}{n^2}$.  As $n \to \infty$, $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[0,1]$.

I am able to find $f$ for $f_n(x)=x^n$, but it is hard for me to find $f$ if $f_n(x)=x^n + \frac{e^{2x}}{n^2}$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I edited your question to make it readable -- let me know if I misrepresented what you intended to write (as it stands, the relation between the text and the picture is not clear).

Comment: No difference. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2x}}{n^2}=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: The picture does not match your question?

Comment: sorry guys, I posted the wrong picture, this is the correct one. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have

$$\frac {e^{2x}}{n^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$

and

$$x^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \begin{cases} 0\text{ if $x\ne 1$} \\ 1\text{ if $x=1$.}\end{cases}$$

I think you can conclude from here by taking the sum.